# Calculating joint probabilities from conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I need to calculate the probability of $P(L,D)$, where $L$ and $D$ are not independent. I have estimated $P(L)$ and $P(D)$ with two distinct models and I also know $P(L|D)$ and $P(D|L)$.

As far as I can see it I have two different estimates of $P(L,D)$:

$P(L,D) =P(L) * P(D|L)$

$P(L,D) =P(D) * P(L|D)$

Am I best off just averaging these two estimates for the joint $P(L,D)$?

Comment: The question as posed is nice and straightforward to read, but some other info it would be useful to add in at the end: 1) What kind of variables are L and D? Continuous? Categorical? What values can they take?  2) Given know P(L|D) and P(D|L) exactly, could you tell us what they are?  3) What models have you used to estimate P(L) and P(D)? Why?  4) What data do you have access to? It sounds like you have samples from P(L) and samples from P(D), to which you have fitted a model. If so, how many samples from each?   5) What are you going to do with P(L,D) once you know it?

Comment: And why I would like to know: 1) To get an idea of how much missing information there is to infer, given you knowledge of the two conditional distributions. 2) Similar reasons to 1.  3) If you have good reason to believe one model's estimates are closer to the 'true' distribution, you should favour using it .  4) If you have more samples of L than D, for example, estimates of P(L) may be more accurate. 5) Depending on the intended application, it may be best to keep *both* estimates of P(L,D).

Comment: 1) What kind of variables are L and D? Continuous? Categorical? What values can they take? 

They are continuous probabilities, so can take values between 0 amd 1?

2) Given know P(L|D) and P(D|L) exactly, could you tell us what they are? 

P(L|D) = 0.385, P(D|L) = 0.735

3) What models have you used to estimate P(L) and P(D)? Why?

Comment: I have two linear regression models to estimate each value. I want to estimate whether things and L and D are the same time. I could build a third model but wondered if I could use the two I have.

4) What data do you have access to? It sounds like you have samples from P(L) and samples from P(D), to which you have fitted a model. If so, how many samples from each? 

I have the same set of samples for each model. That's the historical data to calculate the regression values.

Comment: 5) What are you going to do with P(L,D) once you know it? –  Pat 52 mins ago
  
I am going to select those with the highest probablity from a current set of data where neither L or D are known. I want to select the things which are most likely to be L and D at the same time.

I am inclined to keep both estimates and average them.

Comment: Ok. There's a few things I don't understand in your answers. But one thing you said leapt out at me: "I have the same set of samples for each model. That's the historical data to calculate the regression values. " So, does this mean you have paired data? As in, your dataset has samples $(l_1,d_1), (l_2,d_2), \ldots$ where each pair $(l_i, d_i)$ tells you the value of L and D at the same time? If so, and if you're able to, I strongly advise building a third model using these pairs to directly find out what you want to know. It's almost certainly the best way to estimate P(L,D) from your data.

Comment: Thanks. It's not quite that simple. I do have l and d pairs as you say, but they are derived from other variables which are integers (I am using a probit model). So l is 1 if g is < 3 (i.e. g=[0,1,2]) otherwise 0, and d is 1 if f=a, otherwise 0). But there are 4 possible combinations of l and g so I could probably do a probit model based on that new variable.

Comment: Why can't you just count up the fraction of instances for each of the four cases, i.e. the joint distribution, and then compute the marginal/conditional probabilities when you need them?  If you do that, your two "different" estimates are identitical.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two estimators, call them $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$, of the same parameter $\beta$, then you can combine them in a variety of ways.  Let's suppose you know that the two estimators are consistent and asymptotically normal --- this is generally true of estimators you get from maximum likelihood methods, method of moments methods, and some other methods as well.  Furthermore, suppose you know the (asymptotic) variances of the two estimators, $V(\hat{\beta}_1)$ and $V(\hat{\beta}_2)$ and the covariance of the two estimators $Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)$.

You propose a combined estimator of $\beta$ given by $\frac{1}{2}\hat{\beta}_1+\frac{1}{2}\hat{\beta}_2$.  This is consistent and asymptotically normal if $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$ are.  What is its variance?
\begin{align}
V(\frac{1}{2}\hat{\beta}_1+\frac{1}{2}\hat{\beta}_2) &= \frac{1}{4}V(\hat{\beta}_1) +\frac{1}{4}V(\hat{\beta}_2) +\frac{1}{2}Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2) 
\end{align}

This estimator might be better (lower variance) or worse than either $\hat{\beta}_1$ or $\hat{\beta}_2$.  If, say, $\hat{\beta}_1$ has a crazy-high variance, then the variance of $\frac{1}{2}\hat{\beta}_1+\frac{1}{2}\hat{\beta}_2$ might be higher than the variance of $\hat{\beta}_2$.  We would like to avoid this.  Also, we would like to find the best (i.e. lowest variance) way of combining the two estimators while preserving consistency.  That is, we want to solve:
\begin{align}
&min_{\lambda}V(\lambda\hat{\beta}_1+(1-\lambda)\hat{\beta}_2)\\
&min_{\lambda}\lambda^2V(\hat{\beta}_1)+(1-\lambda)^2V(\hat{\beta}_2)
+2\lambda(1-\lambda)Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)
\end{align}
The first order condition is:
\begin{align}
2\lambda V(\hat{\beta}_1)-2(1-\lambda)V(\hat{\beta}_2)
+2(1-2\lambda)Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)&=0 \\
\frac{V(\hat{\beta}_2)-Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)}{V(\hat{\beta}_1)+V(\hat{\beta}_2)-2Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)} &= \lambda
\end{align}
The combined estimator is then:
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}_* = \frac{V(\hat{\beta}_2)-Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)}{V(\hat{\beta}_1)+V(\hat{\beta}_2)-2Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)} \hat{\beta}_1 +
\frac{V(\hat{\beta}_1)-Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)}{V(\hat{\beta}_1)+V(\hat{\beta}_2)-2Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)} \hat{\beta}_2
\end{align}
Because of the way we set up $\lambda$ in the minimization, you are assured that this new estimator is consistent.  Notice, if the covariance between the two estimators is zero, then this new estimator is just the weighted sum of the two original estimators where the original estimators are weighted inversely to their variance---the new estimator "pays attention" to the old estimators inversely according to their variances.

Finally, the variance of the new estimator is:
\begin{align}
V(\hat{\beta}_*) = \frac{V(\hat{\beta}_1)V(\hat{\beta}_2)-2Cov^2(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)}{V(\hat{\beta}_1)+V(\hat{\beta}_2)-2Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)}
\end{align}

This process of optimally combining multiple estimators is called "minimum distance estimation" in econometrics.  A cite is chapter 13 in Greene, *Econometric Analysis, seventh ed*.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the answer to this question:

"Why are (P(L) * P(D|L)) and (P(D) * P(L|D)) different?".

If it depends on the fact that the model for P(L|D) is unreliable you should only keep (P(L) * P(D|L)), if you have no idea you can consider taking the average.

Comment: I generate P(L) and P(D) from two different models. I do not know which is best.